# Hyperlink from web page to exact tab and cell in excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, hyperlink

I need to provide hyperlinks to Excel files from a website.  The link needs to open the Excel file on specific tab with a specific cell highlighted.  I have read around and have found the following format (fake web address/file name used) to do this:

> "a
>   href="http://www.testdomain.com/excelfiles/fileA.xlsx#Sheet3!C20">Test
>   link

The Excel file opens but only on the first tab in the Excel file. I'm using Excel 2010. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?  Or even know if it is actually possible?

Comment: I'm looking for the answer for this too. The links work well when you do it from another excel sheet or even MS Word. However, from a web page, no dice. Have you had any luck?